# How can I determine if this function is continuous at x=1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

Is 2/0 a discontinuity or infinity for a function?

For the question: Given the function $ (x^2+1)/(x-1) $, is the function continuous at x=1?

When I took the right hand and left limits, I got infinity in both cases and f(1) would be 2/0 which I was informed equals infinity, yet there is a vertical asymptote at x=1, which is an obvious indicator of discontinuity. In this case, will the function be continuous?

Comment: Do you mean the function defined by $f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x-1}$?

Comment: Or do you mean $x^2+(1/x)-1$ or $(x^2)+1/(x-1)$?

Comment: The function is not defined at $x=1$, so there is no question of continuity.

Comment: $2/0$ does not equal infinity. Infinity is a concept not a number. It would be better to say that $2/0$ is undefined in arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function $f(x)$ to be continuous at some point $c$ of its domain, it has to satisfy the following three conditions:

1. $f$ has to be defined at $c$
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$ has to exist
3. the value of the limit must equal to $c$

In your case, the function $\frac{x^2+1}{x-1}$ is not defined at $x=1$, so the function is not continuous.

Comment: A typo on 3: The value must be equal to $f(c)$.